# How can I create an alias for `dbstep` inside the matlab debugger?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the terminal debugger of MATLAB. 
Among the various commands, one frequently has to type `dbstep` or `dbstep in` to advance line  per line.

Using the GUI debugger is not an option for me.

I'm used to the gnu debugger, which makes it very simple to advance (typing `n`) is sufficient and an additional <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeats that command.

I tried to mimic this behavior in matlab by creating a file `n.m` containing

```
function n()
     dbstep;
end
```

when I call this in the MATLAB debugger,

```
K>> n
End of function n.
K>>
```

a separate debug context is opened, which I have to close by using `dbquit`, but no advancing in the original debug context is performed.

Furthermore, I tried:

- adding `dbstop` before `dbstep` inside the `n.m` file: this prevents opening a new debug context, but also does not advance.
- using an anonymous function `n = @dbstep`, but calling `n` like this just prints its definition.

Is there a way to define keyborad shortcuts to debugging commands in matlab? Or is there a way to enable the GUI keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>F10</kbd>), which do not work in the/my terminal.